# Passing iterator by reference gives an error: cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const data' to 'data &

Tags: c++, stl

I have a function `int func(data& dt)`.
It`s need to use the list of structures`lst`. It`s proposed that map and list has some elements (but in my example it has one element). I have to iterate through list and push each element into the `func` function by reference.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>
#include <list>
#include <string>

typedef struct{
    char inf[3];
}data;

std::map<int, data*> mp;
std::list<data> lst;

int func(data& dt){

    ...
}

int main(){

     ...
    //iterate through list
    std::list<data>::const_iterator iterator;

    for (iterator = lst.begin(); iterator != lst.end(); ++iterator) {
        data param = *iterator;
        func(param); 
        //func(*iterator); // doesn`t work!
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The problem is: `func` doesn`t work with *iterator. Why should I do this:`data param = *iterator` to make it work? 
Thank you for help!

Comment: When you say "doesn't work", what do you mean by that? Do you get build errors? Do you get runtime errors? Do you get wrong results? You need to specify that, including the actual errors if there are any.

Comment: Ah, I`m sorry. Doesn`t work = error C2664: 'func' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const data' to 'data &'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`iterator` is actually a `const_iterator`:

```
std::list<data>::const_iterator iterator;
```

but the function you try to pass its target to expects a non-const reference:

```
int func(data& dt){
```

A `const_iterator` cannot give you a non-const reference. You need to either use a non const `std::list<data>::iterator`, or change the function to work with a `const data&` parameter. On the surface, it looks like there is no requirement for the parameter to be non-const reference.

Comment: Thank you! It`s my careless mistake.
Everything is clear with const, yes. So, why works this: data param = *iterator? Here is no const, but it works.

Comment: @user3856196 That works too, because you make a copy of the iterator's target (you have to consider whether you want that.) The function then uses a non-const reference to that copy.